# Predicting missing values in recommender System

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix, recommendation-engine, matrix-factorization

I am trying to implement Non-negative Matrix Factorization so as to find the missing values of a matrix for a Recommendation Engine Project. I am using the nimfa library to implement matrix factorization. But can't seem to figure out how to predict the missing values.
The missing values in this matrix is represented by 0.

```
a=[[ 1.          0.45643546  0.          0.1         0.10327956  0.0225877 ]
 [ 0.15214515  1.          0.04811252  0.07607258  0.23570226  0.38271325]
 [ 0.          0.14433757  1.          0.07905694  0.          0.42857143]
 [ 0.1         0.22821773  0.07905694  1.          0.          0.27105237]
 [ 0.06885304  0.47140452  0.          0.          1.          0.13608276]
 [ 0.00903508  0.4592559   0.17142857  0.10842095  0.08164966  1.        ]]

import nimfa
model = nimfa.Lsnmf(a, max_iter=100000,rank =4)
#fit the model
fit = model()
#get U and V matrices from fit
U = fit.basis()
V = fit.coef()
print numpy.dot(U,V)
```

But the ans given is nearly same as a and I can't predict the zero values.
Please tell me which method to use or any other implementations possible and any possible resources.

I want to use this function to minimize the error in predicting the values.

error=|| a - UV ||_F + c*||U||_F + c*||V||_F

where _F denotes the frobenius norm

Comment: with what method you want to predict the zero values? mean? freq?

Comment: I have edited the question now.

Comment: The whole idea of the recommendation engine is to compute these missing values. I'm not familiar with nimfa, but do you have to know the theory behind what the framework is using to compute recommendations?

Comment: I have read many research papers related to this. But can't seem to figure out how to implement this so as to predict the missing values.

Comment: I voted down this question because it actually lacks research. First thing I have done with no knowledge of the used framework is checking it's official documentation. (which is well referenced too) It seems like the Lsnmf method used to create an **Alternating Nonnegative Least Squares Matrix Factorization Using Projected Gradient** method for each subproblem. Thus a starting point is set.

Comment: The official documentation also references the [paper](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/pgradnmf.pdf)  which defines the used algorithm implementation which accord to the OP, he seems to have read. (also well referenced by google)

Answer (score 1):

I have not used **nimfa** before so I cannot answer on exactly how to do that, but with **sklearn** you can perform a preprocessor to transform the missing values, like this:

```
In [28]: import numpy as np

In [29]: from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

# prepare a numpy array 
In [30]: a = np.array(a)

In [31]: a
Out[31]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.45643546,  0.        ,  0.1       ,  0.10327956,
         0.0225877 ],
       [ 0.15214515,  1.        ,  0.04811252,  0.07607258,  0.23570226,
         0.38271325],
       [ 0.        ,  0.14433757,  1.        ,  0.07905694,  0.        ,
         0.42857143],
       [ 0.1       ,  0.22821773,  0.07905694,  1.        ,  0.        ,
         0.27105237],
       [ 0.06885304,  0.47140452,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,
         0.13608276],
       [ 0.00903508,  0.4592559 ,  0.17142857,  0.10842095,  0.08164966,
         1.        ]])
```

---

```
In [32]: pre = Imputer(missing_values=0, strategy='mean')

# transform missing_values as "0" using mean strategy
In [33]: pre.fit_transform(a)
Out[33]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.45643546,  0.32464951,  0.1       ,  0.10327956,
         0.0225877 ],
       [ 0.15214515,  1.        ,  0.04811252,  0.07607258,  0.23570226,
         0.38271325],
       [ 0.26600665,  0.14433757,  1.        ,  0.07905694,  0.35515787,
         0.42857143],
       [ 0.1       ,  0.22821773,  0.07905694,  1.        ,  0.35515787,
         0.27105237],
       [ 0.06885304,  0.47140452,  0.32464951,  0.27271009,  1.        ,
         0.13608276],
       [ 0.00903508,  0.4592559 ,  0.17142857,  0.10842095,  0.08164966,
         1.        ]])
```

You can read more [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.fit_transform).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't want to use mean but I would like something of the type mean squared error or gradient solution.

Comment: @user3131706, ok cause it's not so clear beforehand. Perhaps look at [GrapghLassoCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.GraphLassoCV.html#sklearn-covariance-graphlassocv)? I'm off so will try to get back at weekends :)

Comment: Does this work for missing values as well? i.e. if I wanted to predict missing values in sparse matrix, will this method work?

Comment: @Sangram, sorry I didn't reply earlier, yes `Imputer` can predict and fill the missing values both for array (column-wise) and sparse matrix.

Comment: @Sangram, here is the docs from [scikit-learn Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html)